# Why the number of first table is zero in latex?

Tags: tables, numbering

I have prepared an article in LaTeX. There is 6 tables in this paper. The number of first table (table caption) apear in zero!. Why the number of first table is zero in latex? How can I convert it in Table 1 (in caption)?

Comment: by default it would be 1 so some code you have not shown is setting it to zero. Please always include a complete small document that shows the problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: do you really get **Table 0** or do you get **Table 0.1** ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: as above, please give us a [complete small document](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to show the problem.